# fonts are not loading for NativeScript on ios

Tags: fonts, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Fonts are not loading on my iphone simulator.
I followed the instructions listed https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#using-fonts. However, the fonts got loaded for android, but not ios.

Code:

```
Label {
  font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
}
```

I have added font OpenSans-Regular to app/fonts folder.

Answer (score 8):

iOS is looking for the font name and not the font file name.
In order for your font to appear in iOS you need to refer with its original font name. To see the original font-name under MacOS open the font with **Font Book** application and you will see the name at the top in the center. I think that the original name you are looking for is **"Open Sans"** (without -Regular)

Your code will work if you keep the original font name and change the CSS to the following code

```
.icon {
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   font-size: 48;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are developing app for both Android and iOS the best practice is to rename the file to the name that iOS is using - I think using underscore for blank spaces with solve it to reuse it in both Android and iOS

Answer (score 1):

Common solution for both operating systems

```
Label { 
   font-family: 'Open Sans', 'OpenSans-Regular';
}
```